# How do i evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -2}\frac {\sqrt{x+2}}{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2} )}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

How do i evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -2}\frac {\sqrt{x+2}}{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{2} )}$.

I'm confused in wolfram alpha the result is $0$ however $\sqrt{x}$ at $x=-2$

is undefined in $\mathbb{R}$ then how it is $0$ ?

Comment: I said this but why in wolfram alpha take it 0 ?

Comment: Wolfram alpha likely doesn't restrict itself to $\Bbb R$. If you allow complex values, then there are two choices, but they both leave the denominator non-zero while the numerator is $0$, so the entire limit is $0$.

Comment: That is the answer.  The fact that $\sqrt{-2}$ is multi-valued is of no consequence.  It is not zero.  The numerator clearly tends to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wolfram alpha treats it as complex numbers. In that case, you can just substitute $x=-2$ and you get zero.

Restricted to the reals, however, the limit makes no sense because the expression is not defined in a neighborhood of $-2$.

Comment: Can you say why you multiplied and divided by $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Just an old habit. It is actually not needed, so I edited the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt x+\sqrt 2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to -2}\sqrt{x+2}\times \lim_{x\to -2} \frac{1}{\sqrt x+\sqrt 2}$$
$$=\sqrt{-2+2}\times \frac{1}{\sqrt {-2}+\sqrt 2}$$
$$=(0)\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}+i\sqrt 2}$$
$$=\color{red}{0}$$

Comment: Then you ristricted it to C ?

Comment: You are absolutely right.